# change colour of one country on googlemaps api

Tags: javascript, php, maps

I need to target just one country as part of a style, within snazzymaps, if possible. OR if not possible, I need to be able to implement a kml within a seperate script call in a custom header.php file for a page. I just need it to highlight America with a specific background color? Is this possible at all or is this not doable?

I hope that someone can help. I think i'm close to how to make it work, I just can't seem to work it out...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, google maps api allows to color only all countries at once. My solution was to take array of country border vertices and use Gmap API to draw polygon on them.

Comment: blast.. thats what i thought.. I think that it might be a lot of work to get them for the countries in mind... ah well. Was worth an ask.